# SQL Server - Deadlock on clustered index

Tags: sql-server, deadlock, clustered-index, non-clustered-index

i have a table A with a clustered index on the primary key and a non-clustered index on a second column (act_id) (foreign Key to table B)

Two update statements are generating following deadlock:
[Deadlock 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsvDb.png)

This deadlock seems not to be an bookmark lookup deadlock, because it's on the same index and the same objid. Including the pk in the non-clustered index has not brought any success. 
I did understand, that the objid is not the recordid, but a range in the index.

The queries (e.g. update a set act_id = 1 where act_id = 2), leading to this deadlock, have the following execution plan:
[Execution plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fOWl.png)

Sometimes the same deadlock is on another table with only one clustered index: [Same deadlock on another table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzJki.png)

Has anybody an idea how this deadlock can be avoided?

Comment: Are there multiple statements in your transactions? Can you post the SQL for the whole transaction?

Answer (score 2):

Both queries seem to be updating the same part of the B-Tree of your Clustered Index.
There's multiple answers to this concurrency issue. One would be to get faster hardware. Another one would be to not have a primary key that can change.

I would first ask you: are you updating your primary key from 2 separate queries?
Do you have a natural key?
Do you have cascading updates set on your primary/foreign keys?
What's your other blocking query?

> Including the pk in the non-clustered index has not brought any success

That's because the pk is always in all the non-clustered indexes, how else would it do a bookmark lookup?

Comment: He's changing a non-PK column. Normally, U-locks prevent many kinds of deadlocks for simple single-row updates. For example, concurrent updates by PK on the same row never deadlock. I'm not sure about updates through non-PK columns in this regard.

Comment: Both queries are of the same kind (update A set act_id where act_id = XX), it's possible that there are more than one row per act_id

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your answers.
I drawed a picture to make it more clear: [image]

We have tasks, which have one action. Each action can have multiple parameters.
Our application consists of several deployments. Each deployment can upload these tasks.
In the example i have three deployments. 2 addons and one base-module.
The 2 addons are waiting until the base-module is ready, then both modules are calling .upload() in the base-module in own transactions. At one point the tasks will be updated (if there were changes). So in both addons were changes in tasks, this generates the deadlock.